# unable to move multiple items in the list up or down in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code in jquery code to move the list item up or down in the list on the click of up and down buttons.

```
            $("#btn-move-up").click(function () {
            $item = $(".highlight");
            $before = $item.prev();
            $item.insertBefore($before);
        });

    //onclick of move down button, move the item down in the list
        $("#btn-move-down").click(function () {
            $item = $(".highlight");
            $after = $item.next();
            $item.insertAfter($after);
        });
```

The code works fine for the single item but if you select multiple items, it start behaving unexpectedly.the [working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/qq9puL75/).
Can someone please point out the mistake in my code or any other better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to select the first item of the list before inserting before, and last item before inserting after. Else it would insert before or after for every item highlighted:

```js
$("#btn-move-up").click(function() {
  $item = $(".highlight");
  $before = $item.first().prev();
  $item.insertBefore($before);
});

//onclick of move down button, move the item down in the list
$("#btn-move-down").click(function() {
  $item = $(".highlight");
  $after = $item.last().next();
  $item.insertAfter($after);
});


$('ul').on("click", "li", function(e) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('highlight')) {
    $(this).removeClass('highlight');
  } else {

    $(this).addClass('highlight');

  }
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn-move-up" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Up"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i>Up</button>

<button type="button" id="btn-move-down" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Down"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>Down</button>

<ul id="fields">
  <li>Ist</li>
  <li>2nd</li>
  <li>3rd</li>
  <li>4th</li>
</ul>
```